# Converting to swift 3 ruined my code

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3

I was updating a project to Swift 3 from Swift 2.3 and it messed up almost all my code. For some reason it added random "_" everywhere and replaced random letters with other letters. It even messed up system functions like in the app delegate

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: U_ IApplication) {

}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application:_  UIApplication) {

}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ applicatio_ n: UIApplication) {

}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ applicat_ ion: UIApplication) {

}
```

As you can see there are random "_" placed throughout. It also moved lines of code onto one line or just added a bunch of extra characters such as:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView:_  UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPattth) -> UITa ViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: tabl(wArray[(indexP: th as NSInd(exPath).r as NSindexPath).row], for)

    cell.textLabel!.text = tableArray[(indexPath (as NSInde as NSIndexPath)xPath).row]
    cell.textLabel!.textColor = UIColoe        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackk 
    return cell
}
```

Has this happened to anyone before and is there a way to stop this from happening again. I tried to revert the code back to Swift 2.3 but it didn't change anything. Also is there a way to retrieve older save logs, because this was a fairly new project so I did not have a back-up.

Comment: If you have Time Machine enabled that would be one way to go back to the earlier version. For future reference, age of project aside, just before performing any mass operation like this would be a great time to take a copy of the entire thing. Or even better put every project you ever start into source control - even a local git repo which xcode will create automatically for you if you let it...

Comment: According to [Swift.org](https://swift.org/migration-guide/): "The first argument label in functions is now considered API by default. The migrator adds underscore labels to preserve the existing APIs".

Comment: This definitely shouldn't happen. You should file a bug report for both Apple and Swift.org

Comment: As others have pointed out, underscores preserve the callee code while meet the new swift3 naming convention, the same holds true for some classes name, Swift3 is still on development bugs still may happens on migration.